# Serving HTML/CSS/JS with Rocket

Tags: html, css, rust, backend, rust-rocket

I am attempting to use the Rust Rocket framework to serve as my backend for hosting my website, but I am struggling to serve basic HTML files and their associated files.

As far as things go, this is the code for my "website". I really am unsure how to do this, and as a novice to backend development, I figured I would see if there was an answer here.

```rs
#[macro_use] extern crate rocket;


use std::fs::File;

use rocket::{response::{Redirect}, fs::FileServer};

#[get("/")]
fn index() -> Redirect {
    let redirect = Redirect::to(uri!("/home"));
    redirect
}

#[launch]
fn rocket() -> _ {
    rocket::build().mount("/", routes![index])
}
```

I am unsure what the best way to structure my front-end files. Any advice/help is appreciated. Please go easy on me, as I am a inexperienced when it comes to backend development.

I have tried the static examples listed on the GitHub, however, I think run into issues where I can view the HTML page but images, CSS, and JavaScript files are not served properly.

Comment: You need to include a bit more information. As it stands, you've imported `FileServer` but aren't using it, so of course your CSS and JS files aren't served. In fact, I don't know how the HTML *is*. (Ignore me if you already know this, but `FileServer` "exposes" a given directory to the web, so when someone goes to `mysite.com/my_static_files_dir/index.html`, the `index.html` file is fetched. The HTML contains `<link>` tags that instruct the browser to fetch the needed CSS files and `<script>` tags that do the same for JS, so it reaches into that directory again. That's what you gotta set up.)

Comment: After continuing to research, accompanied by the feeling of banging one's head against a wall, I figured it out. I understand now how my original question was confusing. I will be posting a solution I ended up finding on my own. I appreciate your help, regardless!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the code that ended up working best for me. I would like to break this down for anyone who may be struggling to get into backend web development, especially for rust.

```
#[macro_use] extern crate rocket;


use rocket::{fs::NamedFile, response::Redirect};
use std::path::{Path, PathBuf};


#[get("/")]
fn index() -> Redirect {
    let redirect = Redirect::to(uri!("/home"));
    redirect
}

#[get("/home")]
async fn home () -> Option<NamedFile> {
    NamedFile::open("client/index.html").await.ok()
}


#[get("/<file..>")]
async fn files(file: PathBuf) -> Option<NamedFile> {
    NamedFile::open(Path::new("client").join(file)).await.ok()
}


#[launch]
fn rocket() -> _ {
    rocket::build().mount("/", routes![index, home, files])
}
```

I will start with the first section.

```
#[macro_use] extern crate rocket;


use rocket::{fs::NamedFile, response::Redirect};
use std::path::{Path, PathBuf};
```

^ This is just our declarations of what I needed to use.

```
#[get("/")]
fn index() -> Redirect {
    let redirect = Redirect::to(uri!("/home"));
    redirect
}

#[get("/home")]
async fn home () -> Option<NamedFile> {
    NamedFile::open("client/index.html").await.ok()
}
```

^ This section is for redirecting the blank, index URL to not give a 404, and to go to a URL with "/home" at the end. This is just for my personal preference, but now you know how to do it too!

In the end, I determined by looking at the Rust analyzer examples for NamedFile, how to specifically open different files.

```
#[get("/<file..>")]
async fn files(file: PathBuf) -> Option<NamedFile> {
    NamedFile::open(Path::new("client").join(file)).await.ok()
}
```

^ This section is to handle other files, such as CSS and JavaScript linked in HTML documents. I imagine this is not a very secure method, but for a portfolio website, I don't need very robust security.

```
#[launch]
fn rocket() -> _ {
    rocket::build().mount("/", routes![index, home, files])
}
```

^ Finally, you just end up mounting the routes. Doing it this way seemed to work for me. I'm sure someone smarter with more experience can explain it in a more elegant way than I have, but if you're in a pinch like me and you're at your wit's end, hopefully, this is a much-needed life preserver when you are drowning.

Comment: I'm glad you got it working! A tip: you don't need to manually load the files. `fs::FileServer` automates that. A route to, for example, `/style.css` will automatically fetch the file (provided you've set it up to point to the directory that contains the `style.css`). Here's an example in the docs: https://docs.rs/rocket/0.5.0-rc.2/rocket/fs/struct.FileServer.html#example

Comment: @verified_tinker I think with the current way my directory is set up using the file system does not work for me. I tried doing something similar to the rust doc and kept getting 404 errors whenever I tried to get those files. I appreciate the tip, for now, I'm gonna do what works for me unless it becomes a problem lol. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I've come up with a much easier solution. You can simply use `FileServer` to host your static files like this:

```
#[launch]
fn rocket() -> _ {
    rocket::build()
        .mount("/", routes![index])
        .mount("/css", FileServer::from(relative!("/templates/css")))
        .mount("/js", FileServer::from(relative!("/templates/js")))
        .mount("/fonts", FileServer::from(relative!("/templates/fonts")))
        .mount("/img", FileServer::from(relative!("/templates/img")))
        .attach(Template::fairing())
}
```

So whenever my HTML template attempts to call a CSS file, Rocket serves the CSS file from the `/templates/css` directory.